# mySql select result return as array in array

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I'm trying to select the result from the mysql database as an array in array.

MariaDB 10.3

```
$fetch = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("SELECT id, name, (SELECT JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('code',(SELECT code FROM zip WHERE id = zip)),JSON_OBJECT('name',(SELECT name FROM zip WHERE id  = zip)))) AS zip FROM orders WHERE id = '188'");

$rows = array();
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch);
$rows['PLZ'] = $r;

print_r($rows);
```

I get the following result

```
Array ( [PLZ] => Array ( [id] => 188 [name] => Boban [zip] => [{"code": "1140"}, {"name": "Penzing"}] ) )
```

the result I expect is

```
Array ( [PLZ] => Array ( [id] => 188 [name] => Boban [zip] =>  Array ( [code] => 1140 [name] Penzing) ) )
```

Can somebody help me?

**SOLVED**

```
$fetch = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("SELECT id, name, (SELECT JSON_OBJECT('code',(SELECT code FROM zip WHERE id = zip),'name',(SELECT name FROM zip WHERE id  = zip))) AS zip FROM orders WHERE id = '188'");

$rows = array();
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch);
$rows['PLZ'] = $r;

foreach ($rows as &$row) {
    $row['zip'] = json_decode($row['zip'], true);
}

print_r($rows);
```

I solved, with the help of Lajos Veres with option a), and little change in sql

Answer (score 0):

a)
I think probably the easiest way to convert your result object from json to php array assuming you want to keep this array structure:

```
foreach($rows as &$row) {
    $row['zip'] = json_decode($row['zip'], true);
}
```

b)
Otherwise I would just rework the query to return the needed data in distinct fields:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    (SELECT code FROM zip WHERE id = zip) as code,
    (SELECT name FROM zip WHERE id = zip) as zip
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    id = '188'
```

Comment: a) Result:      `Array ( [PLZ] => Array ( [id] => 188 [name] => Boban [zip] => Array ( [["code", "1140"]] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => Penzing ) ) ) )`  b) Result:      `Array ( [PLZ] => Array ( [id] => 188 [name] => Boban [code] => 1140 [zip] => Penzing ) ) `   I need this result:      `Array ( [PLZ] => Array ( [id] => 188 [name] => Boban [zip] =>  Array ( [code] => 1140 [name] Penzing) ) )`